# Installing artillery on aws-lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, artillery

I'm interested in using aws-lambda to generate load with Artillery.  Does anyone know if I can load Artillery onto a Lambda instance?  If so, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It's an NPM module. Have you tried following the instructions for including an NPM module in your Lambda deployment package? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Comment: Have a look at `serverless-artillery` (https://github.com/Nordstrom/serverless-artillery)

Answer (score 1):

Artillery has built-in support for running tests in Lambda. You can use the `run-lambda` command for this:

```yaml
artillery run-lambda --region eu-west-1 test.yml
```

More info on how to run tests from AWS Lambda:

- [Distributed Load Testing on AWS Lambda](https://www.artillery.io/docs/load-testing-at-scale/aws-lambda)